# How to delete a Cell with a particular Tag in Mathematica 8?

Tags: front-end, cells, user-interface, compatibility

If I have a `Cell` with a particular tag `CellTag->"MyCell"`, I could delete it in *Mathematica* 9 or later with

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags->"MyCell"]]
```

Unfortunately, `Cells` is a relatively new function, introduced in version 9.  How do I achieve the same task in Version 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SetSelectedNotebook[nb]; 
NotebookLocate["MyCell"]; 
NotebookDelete[SelectedNotebook[]]
```